# View customers on basis of current region in Netsuite

Tags: filter, netsuite, region

In Netsuite, I want that whenever user see the customer list, he can see only the customers which belong to the state from where user sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Region sorting can be done easily by creating a custom view (uses saved search). But it would be almost impossible to sort it by the user's login location(physical location), since Netsuite doesn't have a built in location resolver based on user's IP.

You can build some web application with reverse IP resolver to resolve user's location based on user's IP then tie it in with search result from NS and push the resolved location to use in sorting the search result. It would be a tricky and difficult solution, you need to assess the cost effectiveness of this feature is it worth all these effort?

Sam Azad